# How to send proactive message in a new thread to group chat with Botframework V4

Tags: javascript, node.js, botframework

Some information about my setup:

The user adds the bot to a **Teams Channel**. A command is send to the bot in this channel e.g. `@botname /link <unique code>`.

The bot will verify if this `unique code` exists in a database, if it exists it will save the `context` from this `/link` command to a database. At the same time this Teams channel is linked to the user who created the `unique code` in another app which uses the same database/backend.

Within this other (web) app the user can subscribe to work events. When the creator of the event changes something **I want a (proactive) message to be send to the linked Teams channel** (so a group chat, not a 1-on-1 chat). This message should be in a new thread.

As I have saved the context of the channel to the database I assumed it would be pretty easy to send a message to this channel in a new thread using `createConversationAsync` but this does not seem as easy as it sounds.

I have the bot working using the [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/typescript_nodejs/16.proactive-messages), but this will send the message in the same thread as the /link command was given.

How can I send the message in a new thread by modifying the following code:

```
server.get('/api/notify', async (req, res) => {
    // get conversationReference from database
    const conversationReference = .....(a valid conversationReference)


    await adapter.continueConversationAsync(process.env.MicrosoftAppId, conversationReference, async (turnContext) => {
        await turnContext.sendActivity("This is a proactive message");
    });


    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.write('Proactive messages have been sent.');
    res.end();
});
```

In the above code I have 'hardcoded' the database request of the the conversationReference, if I get this working this will obviously change by using a POST request where some sort of parameter is passed which will be used to look up the corresponding conversationReference.

If anything is unclear please let me know, I am kinda new to Javascript and my native language is not english :)

Thanks in advance!